# Extract multiple info from one line

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have the next log info from a Quake 3 server

```
187:38 ClientUserinfo: 1 \ip\192.168.10.22:27960\challenge\-642334061\qport\26940\protocol\68\name\^3exc3ls!or_^87\rate\8000\sex\male\handicap\100\color2\5\color1\4\snaps\20\authc\0\cl_guid\K3F07049EDE8AAF58CC3A979846237D7
390:06 ClientUserinfo: 14 \ip\192.168.10.21:27960\challenge\314934026\qport\62577\protocol\68\name\Moody_dog55\rate\16000\sex\male\handicap\100\color2\5\color1\4\snaps\20\authc\0\cl_guid\7FB6BDD1F08CCCC8CK3E9444930A35CD
```

I would like to extract the IP and name like this in a file

```
192.168.10.22 ^3exc3ls!or_^87
192.168.10.21 Moody_dog55
```

IP number and name can be in any variety.

How can this be done with sed, awk or grep?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***awk*** approach:

```
awk -F'\' '{gsub(/:.*$/,"",$3); print $3, $11}' file
```

The output:

```
192.168.10.22 ^3exc3ls!or_^87
192.168.10.21 Moody_dog55
```

---

`-F'\'` - considering `\` as field separator

`gsub(/:.*$/,"",$3);` - removing port number from IP address

---

***perl*** approach:

```
perl -nle 'print $1," ",$2 if /\\ip\\([^\\]+):.*?\\name\\([^\\]+)/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You just remove the stuff you don't need, for example with `sed`:

```
sed 's/.*ip\\//;s/:.*\\name\\/ /;s/\\.*//' file
192.168.10.22 ^3exc3ls!or_^87
192.168.10.21 Moody_dog55
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution @Kent